# Material icon size adjustment in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack compose provides a nice Icon() object to display icons that accepts a vector asset. Typically, you are able to set the size via a modifier:

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.PersonPin, Modifier.preferredSize(64.dp))
```

My problem is I cannot seem to affect the size of the displayed icon *when I am using a provided system vector asset* (ie, Icons.Filled. or Icons.Default. etc). When I use my own asset, things work as expected. Using the system assets the modifier only increases the UI footprint of the enclosing "box" while the icon stays tiny within:

[image: Sample from IDE Preview]

Applying the modifier using 'then' results in the same behavior:

```
    Icon(Icons.Filled.PersonPin,Modifier.then(Modifier.preferredSize(128.dp)))
```

Is there something about the native icons? I assumed being vector assets they should be able to resize as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Internally material icon size is `24.dp`

```
// All Material icons (currently) are 24dp by 24dp, with a viewport size of 24 by 24.
@PublishedApi
internal const val MaterialIconDimension = 24f
```

And using the size in modifier it's not working, So we can change the icon by copying the icon and change the default height and width.

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Person.copy(defaultHeight = 128.dp, defaultWidth = 128.dp))
```

> NOTE: This is not an official recommendation to set the icon size,
> Just a hack way to change the icon size.

Comment: Superb thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the explanation - I saw the sizes but didn't imagine they were fixed and did not know about .copy()!

Comment: This no longer works in 1.0.0-alpha11 (see [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178796190)). As per the bug report comments, the new way of doing this from alpha12 on would be `Icon(Icons.Filled.Person, modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp))`

Answer (score 35):

With `1.0.x` just use the [**`Modifier.size(xx.dp)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary.html#size)

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Person,
    "contentDescription",
    modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp))
```

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer no longer works in 1.0.0-alpha11. [This](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178796190) is the associated bug report. As per the bug report comments, the new way of doing this from alpha12 on would be:

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Person, modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp))
```

Comment: Thanks. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

What works for me is to use `Modifier.fillMaxSize(...))`, e.g.

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Person, contentDescription = "Person", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.5F))
```

[image: 0.5]

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Person, contentDescription = "Person", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.75F))
```

[image: 0.75]

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Person, contentDescription = "Person", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(1.0F))
```

[image: 1.0]

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer above more accesible, define some extension functions:

```
fun VectorAsset.resize(size: Int) = this.resize(size.dp)
fun VectorAsset.resize(size: Dp) = this.resize(size, size)
fun VectorAsset.resize(width: Int, height: Int) = this.resize(width.dp, height.dp)
fun VectorAsset.resize(width: Dp, height: Dp) =
  this.copy(defaultWidth = width, defaultHeight = height)
```

Comment: thy, For newer versions: Replace VectorAsset with ImageVector.

Comment: This no longer works in 1.0.0-alpha11 (see bug report). As per the bug report comments, the new way of doing this from alpha12 on would be Icon(Icons.Filled.Person, modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just an `Icon` you can use the `.size()` modifier.

```
Icon(
    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Clear, 
    contentDescription = "clear",
    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
)
```

But if you are using an `IconButton` try using `.scale()` modifier. Because you have to manually adjust the contentPadding if you change the icon size.

```
IconButton(
    onClick = {},
    modifier = Modifier.scale(0.75f)
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Clear, 
        contentDescription = "clear"
    )
}
```